# Using FOR loop to initialise weights using TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am facing the following problem. I want to have a function that given the number of points in each hidden layer, creates the weights for a simple NN.

```
def initialize_parameters(hidden):
        parameters = dict({})

    def W_creator(b,a,i):
        return tf.get_variable("W"+str(i+1), [b,a], initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(seed = 1))
    def b_creator(b,i):
        return tf.get_variable('b'+str(i+1), [b,1], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer())

    for l in range(len(hidden)):
        parameters['W'+str(l+1)] = W_creator(hidden[l+1],hidden[l],l)
        parameters['b'+str(l+1)] = b_creator(hidden[l+1],l)
    return parameters
```

I call this function then using

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    parameters = initialize_parameters()
    print("W1 = " + str(parameters["W1"]))
    print("b1 = " + str(parameters["b1"]))
    print("W2 = " + str(parameters["W2"]))
    print("b2 = " + str(parameters["b2"]))
```

to check everything is fine and an IndexError is raised.

```
     29     for l in range(len(hidden)):
---> 30         W = W_creator(hidden[l+1],hidden[l],l)
     31         parameters['W'+str(l+1)] = W
     32 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Anyone can help with this?

Answer (score 0):

As you use `hidden[l+1]`, your loop has to stop one step earlier, to avoid "out of range" `IndexError`:

```
for l in range(len(hidden)-1):
```